# ASP.NET Core 1.1 Identity dependencies and all Data Access in a separate class library project

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have extracted most of the Database related code from an ASP.NET Core Web Application project with Individual User Accounts, ie. Identity into an ASP.NET Class Library project. I am now stuck in the final pieces which is to remove the concrete assignment to EF Core and moving the connection strings to the Data project.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Created a blank solution
2. Created an ASP.NET Core web
   application (TestPatterns.Web) with Individual User Accounts
3. Updated all the Nuget packages
4. Created a Class Library Core
   package
5. In the Class Library Project (TestPatterns.Data) Nuget ->
   Removed the NetStandard Library 1.6, replaced with
   Microsoft.NetCore.App 1.1.0
6. In the Class Library Project (TestPatterns.Data), added all the EF and
   Identity Nuget Packages

[image: Nuget Packages]

7. Moved over of the 'Data' folder from the
   Web application to the class library project
8. Moved over the
   ApplicationUser.cs file from the Web Application to the class
   library project folder Models

I end up with a structure like this:

[image: Project Structure]

9. To run a migration I execute the following on the Data project folder:

   dotnet ef --startup-project ../TestPatterns2.Web migrations add first

Looking for some help on removing all dependencies of EF Core 1.1 from the Web project and moving the connection strings over. Also, would the DI remain in the Web project or should that move to the Data project also? If so, how?